# Error inserting multiple rows into View with INSTEAD OF trigger

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, database-trigger, database-view

I have a Map table that stores a location using a `GEOGRAPHY` type. Since Entity Framework Core doesn't support spatial types, I have to map a `MapView` view instead with `Lat` and `Long` columns in my application. I then transform these `Lat` and `Long` values to a `geography::Point` when inserting or updating into the view using `INSTEAD OF` triggers.

Example:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[MapViewInsertInstead] ON [dbo].[MapView]
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
IF ((SELECT Lat FROM inserted) IS NOT NULL AND (SELECT Long FROM inserted) IS NOT NULL)
BEGIN
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Map] (HouseId, HousePoint)
    SELECT HouseId
    geography::Point(Lat, Long, 4326)
FROM inserted
END
```

This has worked fine for a while, but I've always been inserting rows one at a time. I'm now doing a bulk-import task of data that includes Map data. When inserting multiple rows into the View at once, like this:

```
INSERT INTO MapView (HouseId, Lat, Long)
VALUES(0x1, 10, 10), (0x2, 10, 10);
```

I get this error:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

So this trigger only works if inserting a single Map row at once. Is there something I can modify inside of the trigger to allow for multiple rows being inserted?

Comment: This is because your trigger has a MAJOR flaw. It assumes only a single row will ever be inserted. Triggers fire once per operation, not once per row. You could just add a where clause in your insert and get rid of the IF statement.

Comment: @SeanLange triggers do not fire once per operation as a rule of thumb. This is true for SQL Server, however not for every other database (eg: Postgresql).

Comment: @KamilG. right but this is clearly a sql server question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because this statement:

```
(SELECT Lat FROM inserted) IS NOT NULL
```

Expects one value to compare with the condition.

What you could do is rewrite the logic by getting rid of `IF` statement and instead incorporate the check within the `INSERT` statement itself:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[MapViewInsertInstead] ON [dbo].[MapView]
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
BEGIN
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Map] (HouseId, HousePoint)
    SELECT HouseId
    geography::Point(Lat, Long, 4326)
FROM inserted
WHERE Lat IS NOT NULL
  AND Long IS NOT NULL
END
```

Comment: It was that simple. Previously we never even had a way to insert more than one at a time so this wasn't an issue.

Answer (score 3):

You probably don't want an invalid INSERT to silently fail.  So just skip the null check and the `geography::Point` function will raise an error if someone attempts to insert a NULL.  EG

```
CREATE OR ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[MapViewInsertInstead] ON [dbo].[MapView]
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    set nocount on;

    INSERT INTO [dbo].[Map] (HouseId, HousePoint)
        SELECT HouseId, geography::Point(Lat, Long, 4326)
    FROM inserted;
END
```